# Unable to deploy RoR to Bluemix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ibm-cloud

I am working on RoR app, and cannot deploy to Bluemix without it crashing.  The error I keep getting is

> "**CRASHED**", "**exit_status"=>1**, "exit_description"=>"**failed to accept connections
>   within health check timeout**", "crash_timestamp"=>1446660973}

What could be causing this to happen, and what are some potential solutions?

I am not specifying a version of Ruby in my gemfile nor am I using a Ruby buildpack to deploy. Both are solutions I have already tried to no avail.

Comment: Could you please add output of  `cf logs app_name --recent`

Answer (score 0):

Do the logs contain anything? This document lists the logging options available in Bluemix:
https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2015/10/22/bluemix-logging-options/
The simplest, as already suggested is cf logs appname --recent.

Comment: I switched up a few things, like updating my version of Ruby, and now I can't even install the ibm_db gem.  I am getting an error that says it cannot build the native extensions.  Is there a workaround that does not involve me installing db2 or any driver?